converting a dataframe to dictionary in python?
I have a dataframe like below:
id|title|url|timed
2|xyz|www.xyz.com|2024-02-01T00:00:00Z|
3|ghy|NaN|2024-03-05T00:00:00Z|
4|None|NaN|2024-04-05T00:00:00Z|
56|ghy|www.ghy.com|2024-05-05T00:00:00Z|

Expected output from this dataframe to dictionary, avoiding the None and NaN from creating as a new key value in this dicts -
{"id":"2","title":"xyz","url":"www.xyz.com","timed":"2024-02-01T00:00:00Z"}
{"id":"3","title":"ghy","timed":"2024-03-05T00:00:00Z"}
{"id":"4","timed":"2024-04-05T00:00:00Z"}
{"id":"56","title":"ghy","url":"www.ghy.com","timed":"2024-05-05T00:00:00Z"}

Any help would be appreciated.

I reopened, this was not the expected logic, the NaNs must be ignored

You can use agg combined with dropna and to_dict:
out = df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1).tolist()

Or, probably more efficient, using the underlying numpy array, a list comprehension, dict and zip:
out = [dict(zip(df.columns[(m:=pd.notna(a))], a[m])) for a in df.values]

# or for older python versions (<3.8)
out = [dict(zip(df.columns[m], a[m])) for a in df.values for m in [pd.notna(a)]]

Output:
[{'id': 2, 'title': 'xyz', 'url': 'www.xyz.com', 'timed': '2024-02-01T00:00:00Z'},
 {'id': 3, 'title': 'ghy', 'timed': '2024-03-05T00:00:00Z'},
 {'id': 4, 'timed': '2024-04-05T00:00:00Z'},
 {'id': 56, 'title': 'ghy', 'url': 'www.ghy.com', 'timed': '2024-05-05T00:00:00Z'}]


it will give that square brackets , using tolist()

@emiley not sure I understood your comment

for rec in out: json.dumps(rec) , will that work?

Yes it will produce a json string for each dictionary. If you don't need the dictionaries you could directly use: df.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().to_json(), axis=1).tolist() or [json.dumps(dict(zip(df.columns[(m:=pd.notna(a))], a[m]))) for a in df.values]

You can use the to_dict() method and use 'records' as the orientation and filter the output using list and dict comprehensions.
import pandas as pd

# recreate the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'id': [2, 3, 4, 56],
 'title': ['xyz', 'ghy', pd.NA, 'ghy'],
 'url': ['www.xyz.com', pd.NA, pd.NA, 'www.ghy.com'],
 'timed': ['2024-02-01T00:00:00Z', '2024-03-05T00:00:00Z', '2024-04-05T00:00:00Z', '2024-05-05T00:00:00Z']
})


# iterate over each dictionary/row and remove the NA values.
[{k: v for k,v in d.items() if not pd.isna(v)} for d in df.to_dict('records')]

# returns:
[{'id': 2, 'title': 'xyz', 'url': 'www.xyz.com', 'timed': '2024-02-01T00:00:00Z'},
 {'id': 3, 'title': 'ghy', 'timed': '2024-03-05T00:00:00Z'},
 {'id': 4, 'timed': '2024-04-05T00:00:00Z'},
 {'id': 56, 'title': 'ghy', 'url': 'www.ghy.com', 'timed': '2024-05-05T00:00:00Z'}]


That was my original idea, but note that this creates a full intermediate in memory ;)

python
dict_list = [{k: v for k, v in row.items() if v is not None and not
pd.isna(v)} for index, row in df.iterrows()]
print(dict_list)

data = {
    'id': [2, 3, 4, 56],
    'title': ['xyz', 'ghy', None, 'ghy'],
    'url': ['www.xyz.com', None, None, 'www.ghy.com'],
    'timed': ['2024-02-01T00:00:00Z', '2024-03-05T00:00:00Z', '2024-04-05T00:00:00Z', '2024-05-05T00:00:00Z']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
aa = df.dropna(subset = df.columns).to_dict(orient='records')

for row_dict in aa:
    print(row_dict)

{'id': 2, 'title': 'xyz', 'url': 'www.xyz.com', 'timed': '2024-02-01T00:00:00Z'}
{'id': 56, 'title': 'ghy', 'url': 'www.ghy.com', 'timed': '2024-05-05T00:00:00Z'}

